# Cloud Spanner: Implication of split being 'too big'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

The documentation states that one split should not be bigger then 'a few GB'.

- Is there a hard limit on that where Cloud Spanner will stop storing more data in one split ?

  - Nothing can be found in the limits-section here: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/quotas
- What is the implication of e.g. splits growing to 20-30GB ?

  - I can think of problems when those splits need to be moved around between instances while being read/written

I know the second point sound like we should split up our primary key/add a sharding-key as first primary-key-part.

But if you have hundreds of customers having really big product catalogs and you need to interleave brand- and category-tables so you can join on them. And alternative approaches of storing one product-catalog in several splits become very slow on secondary index queries (like: query all active products in a catalog).

Thanks a lot in advance because this would help us a lot of understanding Cloud Spanner better for our planned production-use.
Christian Gintenreiter

Comment: So, what you have tried for this? include that in question and post

Comment: You'll get worse performance if you create large splits.

We recommend to architecture your schema in a way to avoid putting more than few GB to a single split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A split can only be served by a single node, so very large splits may cause the single node to become a performance bottleneck. You may start to see performance degradation with a split size greater than 2GB.  The hard limit on split size is bound by the the storage limit for a single node, which is 2TB.

Can you please provide some more details about your schema and interleaving?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rose.
I would love to go deeper on that but as I'm on holiday for 3 weeks now we need to postpone that:

But thanks again!

Comment: @rose-liu would you be able to give precise implication of having a split being too large? For instance would a split that weights for 4.2GB would impact full db performances... Will queries against that split be slightly slower? a lot slower? would that impact other queries not targeting that split?   Also you say 2GB but doc says 4GB. Did that change since you answered or is it the actual limitation?